# Getting XML value from attribute dispatchState with python and request

Tags: python, python-3.x, splunk, splunk-sdk

I'm doing a request to splunk for jobs using:

```
 response = requests.post('https://xxxx.net:8089/services/search/jobs/' + job_id, auth=(splunk_user, splunk_pass), verify=False)
```

Now i look at the output using `print(response.text)`. I want to be able to print just the value of `<s:key name="dispatchState">DONE</s:key>` and see if it's "DONE" or whatever the value is.

Comment: example output:    <author>
    <name>api_something</name>   </author>   <content type="text/xml">
    <s:dict>
      <s:key name="bundleVersion">7235793338819504529</s:key>
      <s:key name="canSummarize">1</s:key>
      <s:key name="cursorTime">1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00</s:key>
      <s:key name="defaultSaveTTL">604800</s:key>
      <s:key name="defaultTTL">600</s:key>
      <s:key name="delegate"></s:key>
      <s:key name="diskUsage">93304</s:key>
      <s:key name="dispatchState">DONE</s:key>

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Since the output format is in xml you can parse the xml using python's `lxml` module as shown below.

```
import lxml.etree as et
root = et.fromstring(response.text)
done_state = root.xpath("//s:key[@name='dispatchState']/text()", root.nsmap)[0]
```

You can install `lxml` using pip

```
pip install lxml
```

You can find the further documentation and tutorials [here](https://lxml.de/index.html).

**Solution 2**

If the structure is constant you can use simple regular expression to get the required information:

```
import re
match = re.search('<s:key name\="dispatchState">(.*?)</s:key>', response.text)
result = match.group(1)
```

You can get more information about regular expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).